# Set a Function Breakpoint on a C# Generic Class/Method in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, debugging, generics, visual-studio-2017, breakpoints

How can I set a [Function Breakpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15d1wtaf(v=vs.100).aspx) on a generic class/method?

I'm possibly trying to figure out the syntax to use. Here is the class/method I want to set it on:-

```
namespace MyCustom.SpecialNS
{
  public class SomeGenericConditionClass<T> : BaseConditionNS.WhenCondition<T> where T : BaseRuleNS.RuleContext
  {

    protected override bool Execute(T ruleContextParam)
    {
        string hello = "Hello. Set Breakpoint here!";
        return true;
    }
  }
}
```

As an FYI, I am attempting to debug a third party dll, in which I have setup other ways to debug regular concrete classes/methods using Function Breakpoints.
i.e I can set

```
MyCustom.SpecialNS.SimpleConcreteClass.BasicExecute(MyCustomAttrNS.MyAttributeType)
```

and it will successfully break.
But for the generic, I'm not sure what the type T is, or what the syntax is to properly set the Function Breakpoint, and it's a third party DLL, so I can't just open the code and click to create the breakpoint.

I have tried

```
MyCustom.SpecialNS.SomeGenericConditionClass.Execute
```

and

```
MyCustom.SpecialNS.SomeGenericConditionClass<T>.Execute<T>
```

And many other variations around it, but I get nowhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `SomeGenericConditionClass<T>.Execute`? I'm not sure about the bit about this being in a 3rd party DLL, but this works in code that I write.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that before but it didn't work. I'll test it again.

Comment: Click Debug, Windows, Breakpoints, click New, Break at function, enter the function, and click OK.
Please make sure that you've turned off the "Enable Just My Code" under Debugging configuration.

Comment: Yeah I know that much. I was after the syntax to use for the 'enter the function' part.

Comment: @asherber That was exactly the syntax I was looking for. I had a weird thing with the 3rd party DLL though. I just needed to touch the Web.config file and try again (a weird side affect of what I was trying to achieve with the DLLs I'm trying to debug). Then the syntax you gave worked for the breakpoint. If you want, add that syntax as an answer here, and I'll accept it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SomeGenericConditionClass<T>.Execute` works for me. (Promoted from my comment above.)